# load different module on preferences

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to process an array of image files. When selecting them I can choose between selecting them randomly or one by one (queue). The decision is hold by the `config.json`.

First I initialize the processor and select the right image selection module by calling `processImages` and pass in the array of image files.

```
function processImages(images) {
    const imageSelector = getImageSelector();
    imageSelector.init(images); // initialize the module

    console.log(imageSelector.getImage()); // test
}

function getImageSelector() {
    const { random } = config;
    const selector = random ? 'randomSelector' : 'queueSelector';
    return require(`./imageSelectors/${selector}.js`);
}
```

The modules itself have their own logic to return the next image. For the random module I go for

```
let images;

module.exports = {
    init: images => {
        init(images);
    },
    getImage: () => {
        return getImage();
    }
};

function init(images) {
    this.images = images;
}

function getImage() {
    const index = getRandomIndex();
    return images[index];
}

function getRandomIndex() {
    const indexValue = Math.random() * images.length;
    const roundedIndex = Math.floor(indexValue);
    return images[roundedIndex];
}
```

and for the queue module I go for

```
let images;
let currentImageCounter = 0;

module.exports = {
    init: images => {
        init(images);
    },
    getImage: () => {
        return getImage();
    }
};

function init(images) {
    this.images = images;
    currentImageCounter = 0;
}

function getImage() {
    const index = getNextIndex();
    return images[index];
}

function getNextIndex() {
    if (currentImageCounter > images.length)
        currentImageCounter = 0;
    else
        currentImageCounter++;

    return currentImageCounter;
}
```

When I run the code and `random` is `true` I get this error

> C:...\imageSelectors\randomSelector.js:22
>
> const indexValue = Math.random() * images.length;
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

When calling `imageSelector.init(images)` some image items are available so they just are undefined within the modules.

I think I missunderstood how to work with modules correctly. Could someone tell me how to setup the code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module, you declare a local variable `images` and use it as an object field `this.images` which is not right. Try this approach and do not shadow the upper-level variables with deeper-level variables with the same names to not be misled (i.e. use `images` as outer variable and something like `imgs` as function parameters). I've also a bit simplified your module code to avoid some unneeded duplication.

```js
let images;

module.exports = {
  init(imgs) {
    images = imgs;
  },
  getImage() {
    const index = getRandomIndex();
    return images[index];
  }
};

function getRandomIndex() {
  const indexValue = Math.random() * images.length;
  const roundedIndex = Math.floor(indexValue);
  return images[roundedIndex];
}
```